# My file type not saving on my database

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I have completed file upload but if the file name is "213134.jpg" but my code store database only name "213134" without file type. Can you please help me. I have used CI for this task

```
function postMessage(){
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/inbox/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
    $config['max_size'] = '2048';
    $config['max_width']  = '3000';
    $config['max_height']  = '3000';
    $random=rand(00000, 99999);
    $id=$this->session->userdata('id');
    $pic=$id*$random;
    $config['file_name'] =$pic;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        }
    else
    {
        $blog_msg ='Sorry, Picture uploaded.';
     }

    $u_id=$this->session->userdata('id');
    $u_name=$this->session->userdata('u_fname');
    $to=$this->uri->segment(3);
    $date= $date=date('d-M-Y');
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $data=array(
        'm_from'=>$u_id,
        'from_name'=>$u_name,
        'm_date'=>$date,
        'm_body'=>$message,
        'm_to'=>$to,
        'm_attach'=>$pic 
        );
}
```

Comment: Where's your database code?

Comment: Fix code tagging, please.

Comment: $inputed=$this->db->insert($this->message,$data);
      $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
      $this->db->trans_complete();
      return  $insert_id;

Comment: `$pic=$id*$random;` should be like this `$pic=$id*$random.'.jpg';`

Comment: Is the type definitely .jpg and not .jpeg? If .jpg use 'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg'

Answer (score 2):

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';//Change this
```

**Method 01**

```
$data=array(
        'm_from'=>$u_id,
        'from_name'=>$u_name,
        'm_date'=>$date,
        'm_body'=>$message,
        'm_to'=>$to,
        'm_attach'=>$this->input->post('pic'), //change this(in your HTML attribute name='' )
        );
```

**Method 02**

or else you can try

```
$ext = pathinfo($pic, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //Get the Extension

$random=rand(00000, 99999);
$id=$this->session->userdata('id');
$pic=$id*$random.$ext;//change this
$config['file_name'] =$pic;
```

Comment: Everything is okay. My project is working on local server.But after uploading online server it works for home page.But others link are not working. [link] (http://technolgia.com/community_medical )

Comment: You forget to uplode .htacess file

Comment: I have htacess file code. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704771/running-codeigniter-in-server/30705469#30705469

Comment: After every page href use index.php. like this ` http://technolgia.com/community_medical/index.php/home/registration`

Comment: In config.php empty these parameters. `Base_url` and `index`

Comment: Yes,it's working with index.php. Is there any other way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79981/discussion-between-ricky-and-abdulla).

Comment: in your config.php file **Change** `$config['base_url'] = '';` and `$config['index_page'] = '';`