# running codeigniter in server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm a beginner in codeigniter. I write my code and run it in localhost in my PC. But when I upload it in host I give this error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/sqlite.so' -
>   /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/sqlite.so:
>   undefined symbol: zval_property_ctor
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:

and "404 not found" error.
At first I think problem should be from htaccess file and delete it. But problem is not solved.
can anybody help me please?
thanks a lot.

Comment: what is live site?? did you include `.htacess`??

Comment: @Abdulla in local it works true. but in live site it doesn't work true! I upload htaccess and test it with and without htaccess.

Comment: did you upload system files correctly??

Comment: upload my .htacess file

Comment: may be you have not uploaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `.htaccess` file. This should be place out side the application folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can I comment 

    extension=pdo_sqlite.so
    extension=sqlite.so

from php.ini with htaccess file?

Comment: are you sure whether you upload system files correctly??

Comment: yes. my htaccess now is `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0

# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log

# prevent access to PHP error log
<Files PHP_errors.log>
 Order allow,deny
 Deny from all
 Satisfy All
</Files>`